# Parsing Date in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

Good day everyone! I have a problem regarding my "date". It needs to be parsed but I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me by suggesting fixes on my code?

```
    <%
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format); 
String faculty = request.getParameter("faculty");
String absent_date = request.getParameter("absent_date");
int intFaculty = Integer.parseInt(faculty);

System.out.println(faculty);
System.out.println(df.parse(absent_date));

java.sql.Date absentdate  = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(absent_date).getDate());
Absences abs = new Absences();
abs.setFaculty_id(intFaculty);
abs.setAbsent_date(absentdate);
int result = AbsencesImpl.AddAbsences(abs);
if (result == 0)
{
%>
    <jsp:forward page="ListAbsences.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="msg" value="Record Successfully Added"/>
    <jsp:param name="ret" value="meron"/>
    </jsp:forward>
<%
}

%>
```

For the result and error in Console:

```
 5 
 Tue May 01 00:00:00 CST 2012
 java.sql.SQLException: 3 values for 2 columns
```

I found this but I dont know how to implement this on my codes.

```
 SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Im using Eclipse Indigo, Sqlite, and Apache Tomcat

Insert Statement (Im using MVC)

```
public int AddAbsences(Absences abs)
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    ConnDB conn = new ConnDB();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO absences( faculty_id, absent_date) VALUES(?, ?)";

    try{
        con = conn.connect();
        try{
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setInt(1, abs.getFaculty_id());
            pstmt.setDate(2, abs.getAbsent_date());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your sql is wrong. You insert 3 values for 2 columns. Show us the insert query.

Comment: I know that's not 100% the answer to your question, but do yourself a favor and use Joda Time whenever you have to work with dates in Java.  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've included the insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend to use

```
df.parse(absent_date).getTime()
```

instead of

```
df.parse(absent_date).getDate()
```

And also, I suspect that you have table absences with 3 columns, but you try to insert only 2 values. If one of values from table is id, then I suspect this value is not autogenerated.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for the answer. It solved both of my problem. Cheers!

Comment: I noticed that the dates that has been inserted at my database were "30.12.1899". All of them. But in the browser or jsp. It displays the selected date. For example : in the browser ("2012-04-24") but in the database ("30.12.1899"). What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to formulate a insert statement which will work from the database management console (which ever is your database), then try to substitute the same in the code with arguments. There  by you will get the date format also. There are some sql date functions which you can use in the query itself which will convert the date from your code readable format.

eg: in MsSQL - cast ('20120312' as datetime) will convert the string date 12-03-2012 into date time.

try to search for sql date functions for your type of database.